# Игра в windows forms c++

Tags: winforms

Это игра, нужно успеть нажать на кнопку пока она активна, но через она исчезает, когда активна другая(для летней практики в вузе доп. задание).
ребят ну вопрос такой: есть ли какой то процесс в самой форме который всё время запрашивается, не такой как при загрузке, когда один раз пробежит и по нему и всё, а чтобы всё время обновлялось?
Ну вообще я изначально делал в кнопке старт, но тогда я не уверен что во время этого можно будет нажимать другие кнопки, а если можно то как проверить нажата ли кнопка пока идёт время игры(минута даётся на неё).
И ещё как узнать что таймер закончил работу.
[image: Игра описанная в вопросе(сыренькая)]

```
#pragma once
#include "ctime"
#include "iostream"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;


namespace Летняяпрактика {

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для Form_Game
    ///
    /// Внимание! При изменении имени этого класса необходимо также изменить
    ///          свойство имени файла ресурсов ("Resource File Name") для средства компиляции управляемого ресурса,
    ///          связанного со всеми файлами с расширением .resx, от которых зависит данный класс. В противном случае,
    ///          конструкторы не смогут правильно работать с локализованными
    ///          ресурсами, сопоставленными данной форме.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form_Game : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form_Game(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form_Game()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button9;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button10;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button11;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button12;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button13;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button14;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button15;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button16;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button_start;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button_out;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^  timer_game;
    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;



    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуется переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
        /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button11 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button12 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button13 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button14 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button15 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button16 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button_start = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button_out = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->timer_game = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this->components));
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(57, 71);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(166, 71);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(276, 71);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 2;
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(382, 71);
            this->button4->Name = L"button4";
            this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button4->TabIndex = 3;
            this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(57, 153);
            this->button5->Name = L"button5";
            this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button5->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button6
            // 
            this->button6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(166, 153);
            this->button6->Name = L"button6";
            this->button6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button6->TabIndex = 5;
            this->button6->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button7
            // 
            this->button7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(276, 153);
            this->button7->Name = L"button7";
            this->button7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button7->TabIndex = 6;
            this->button7->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button8
            // 
            this->button8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(382, 153);
            this->button8->Name = L"button8";
            this->button8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button8->TabIndex = 7;
            this->button8->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button9
            // 
            this->button9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(57, 243);
            this->button9->Name = L"button9";
            this->button9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button9->TabIndex = 8;
            this->button9->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button10
            // 
            this->button10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(166, 243);
            this->button10->Name = L"button10";
            this->button10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button10->TabIndex = 9;
            this->button10->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button11
            // 
            this->button11->Location = System::Drawing::Point(276, 243);
            this->button11->Name = L"button11";
            this->button11->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button11->TabIndex = 10;
            this->button11->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button12
            // 
            this->button12->Location = System::Drawing::Point(382, 243);
            this->button12->Name = L"button12";
            this->button12->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button12->TabIndex = 11;
            this->button12->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button13
            // 
            this->button13->Location = System::Drawing::Point(57, 335);
            this->button13->Name = L"button13";
            this->button13->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button13->TabIndex = 12;
            this->button13->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button14
            // 
            this->button14->Location = System::Drawing::Point(166, 335);
            this->button14->Name = L"button14";
            this->button14->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button14->TabIndex = 13;
            this->button14->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button15
            // 
            this->button15->Location = System::Drawing::Point(276, 335);
            this->button15->Name = L"button15";
            this->button15->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button15->TabIndex = 14;
            this->button15->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button16
            // 
            this->button16->Location = System::Drawing::Point(382, 335);
            this->button16->Name = L"button16";
            this->button16->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 64);
            this->button16->TabIndex = 15;
            this->button16->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button_start
            // 
            this->button_start->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->button_start->Location = System::Drawing::Point(-1, -1);
            this->button_start->Name = L"button_start";
            this->button_start->Size = System::Drawing::Size(133, 40);
            this->button_start->TabIndex = 16;
            this->button_start->Text = L"Старт!";
            this->button_start->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button_start->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form_Game::button_start_Click);
            // 
            // button_out
            // 
            this->button_out->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->button_out->Location = System::Drawing::Point(382, -1);
            this->button_out->Name = L"button_out";
            this->button_out->Size = System::Drawing::Size(133, 40);
            this->button_out->TabIndex = 17;
            this->button_out->Text = L"Выход!";
            this->button_out->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button_out->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form_Game::button_out_Click);
            // 
            // timer_game
            // 
            this->timer_game->Interval = 60000;
            // 
            // Form_Game
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(514, 436);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button_out);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button_start);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button16);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button15);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button14);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button13);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button12);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button11);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button10);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button9);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button8);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button6);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form_Game";
            this->Text = L"Form_Game";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form_Game::Form_Game_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
        void BtnFalse() {
            this->button_out->Enabled = false;
            this->button_start->Enabled = true;
            this->button1->Enabled = false;
            this->button2->Enabled = false;
            this->button3->Enabled = false;
            this->button4->Enabled = false;
            this->button5->Enabled = false;
            this->button6->Enabled = false;
            this->button7->Enabled = false;
            this->button8->Enabled = false;
            this->button9->Enabled = false;
            this->button10->Enabled = false;
            this->button11->Enabled = false;
            this->button12->Enabled = false;
            this->button13->Enabled = false;
            this->button14->Enabled = false;
            this->button15->Enabled = false;
            this->button16->Enabled = false;
        }
    private: System::Void Form_Game_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 BtnFalse();
             }
private: System::Void button_start_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->button_out->Enabled = true;
             this->button_start->Enabled = false;
             this->timer_game->Start();
             int limit = 60000;
             while (/*пока время в таймере не ноль, как?*/) {
                 srand(time(0));
                 int cube = 1 + rand()%16; // для активации рандомной кнопки
                 if ((this->button_out->Tag) == 1) { //пытался сделать проверку нажати кнопки
                     this->button_start->Enabled = true;
                     break;
                 }
             }
                 this->button1->Enabled = true;// решил проверить правильность работы
         }
private: System::Void button_out_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->button_out->Tag = 1;
         }
};
}
```

Код копипастнут может и криво, но вроде всё видно, первый вопрос:)

Comment: Вот здесь норм код: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-cli-winforms/thread1766897.html Это мой же вопрос, но там никто не отвечает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно по кнопке старт крутить ваши действия, постоянно вызывая очередь сообщений чтобы обрабатывать интерфейс. Можно в отдельном потоке это делать.

Самое правильное для такой задачи сделать таймер и по событию таймера работать, запустить его на интервалы миллисекунд на 20-100 и пусть щелкает...

По таймеру, надо запустить его на малые интервалы, и обрабатывать его событие, в нем накапливать счетчик общего времени. В микротиках как раз зажигать и гасить кнопки...

Comment: Да, отлично, так и сделаю, а как узнать что действие таймера закончилось? Событие Tick возникает при его завершении и тогда нужно 2 таймера, один будет активировать новую кнопку, а другой будет уведомлять о завершении игры, так?

Comment: А как получить значение таймера, ну то есть с чем мне сравнивать, к примеру я хочу чтобы значение тиков не превышало 60 000 миллисекунд, а в интервале будет установлен 1000 миллисекунд, каким образом это реализовать?

Comment: не нужно 2 таймера. Нужен 1 таймер на 50 мСек допустим. При нажатии кнопки старт в переменную сохраняете общее время игры в тиках (60*1000/50) - 60 секунд и запускаете таймер. Каждый тик вы из этого переменной вычитаете 1, как дошла до нуля - игре конец, останавливаете таймер.  В этой же функции еще одним счётчиком реализуете таймауты включения кнопок.

Comment: Да уже сделал, написал ещё переменную limit и присвоил ей значение, а значит можно сложность выбирать от времени, и в tick отнимаю 1, и деактивирую кнопку которая выберется в этом же tick если limit != 0 с помощью рандома и активируется, а так же заново активируется таймер.